# WebRequest on @RequestBody object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In Spring MVC. I'm able to use the *WebRequest* as a parameter that will automatically be set (along with other things such as *Locale* etc.).

I'm also using @RequestBody to pass in a JSON object which describes what and how data should be fetched.

Is it possible to get Spring to automatically set the *WebRequest* directly on the *@RequestBody* object *EntriesRequestDTO* (I would make a *WebRequest* field on *EntriesRequestDTO*). This would allow me to hide some complexity since I often need to get an attribute from *WebRequest*.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/entries", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public EntriesDTO getEntries(@RequestBody EntriesRequestDTO request, WebRequest webRequest){
   ...
}
```

Comment: The very short answer is *no*. Ofcourse with creating your own converter/extending the `ObjectMapper` you can do whatever you want but that would require some complexity. But why do you need it shouldn't all the information be already in the JSON?

Comment: I have to access an attribute that is set by a filter earlier in the request.

Comment: Then why not simply retrieve it once and set it on the DTO yourself. Should be a one time action.

Comment: So I guess I could extend  'MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' and register this converter rather than the existing?

Comment: I have many operations where I pass in both objects. So I would have to do this as the first thing in all methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a custom HttpMessageConverter. It is not a very general solution, but it works for me:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public DTOJackonMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        return new DTOJackonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

The *DTOJacksonMessageConverter* extends *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* and overrides *read* method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP to set the WebRequest to the DTO

```
@Around("execution(* (com.your.company..*).*(..))")
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
  //get args[0] and args[1]
  return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Make sure the regex is correct (or add custom annotation), check for cast exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not familiar with the aspect oriented programming. I therefore went with a 'simpler' - at least to me - solution.